# Using sql to generate SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server, I want to count all the rows in all tables in the database

The following statement I have read in the book (O-Reilly-SQL-Cookbook-2nd-Edition-Final)

```
select 'select count(*) from '||table_name||';' cnts
from user_tables;
```

When I run on Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, it raise a error
**Incorrect syntax near '|'.**

I know it only run on Oracle, So I need a version of SQL Server. Because I'm new about dynamic SQL.

Please, help me, thank you so much!

Comment: There is no need for that part, only  count is needed.this is correct "select count(*) from tablename;"

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have `user_tables` nor does it use `||` for an operator. While you can adjust the statement so it does achieve the desired result, I recommend getting either a more general book if you just want to learn SQL (as dynamic SQL should not something a beginner should tackle), or a book specific to SQL Server, so you don't have to effectively translate all constructions you might find in this book, or else install a free/evaluation version of the engine the book is tuned to (in this case it appears to be Oracle).

Comment: Hi @JeroenMostert, thank for your advice, I know a above statement only run Oracle. Now, I want to learn advance SQL, the book said "The following examples are queries that would work on an Oracle system. For other RDBMSs the technique is exactly the same, the only difference being things like the names of the data dictionary tables and date formatting". So, I really need a version of above statement in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is:

```sql
select 'select count(*) FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name)
from sys.tables
```

if you want to directly execute the generated queries, you can use something like:

```sql
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
select @sql = string_agg(
  'select count(*) AS  ' + QUOTENAME('count_' + name) + ' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ';', '
') within group (order by name)
from sys.tables;
exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: thank you, can you give me some keyword about the dynmaic sql in SQL Server

Comment: you mean like tutorial? You might wanna read https://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html :) it's a lot of good info

Comment: While this explains the dynamic SQL aspect, really this is the wrong approach to [counting rows in a table](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/10/t-sql-queries/bad-habits-count-the-hard-way)

Answer (score 2):

You are using SQL server, it doesn't support pipe operator. Use + instead

Comment: the query needs dynammic sql that is simply not enough